# Experimental settings for the Free Will Theorem by Conway and Kochen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement

I would like to know where I can read more details about how to prepare two entangled particles for which the axiom "TWIN" in the paper [Free Will Theorem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0604079.pdf) holds.
The particles must have spin 1 and any measurement of their squared spin components along three orthogonal directions has to give 1,1,0 in some order. The authors provide some indication but I want to go into details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.